Bookdown's gitbook building into a HTML looking website (does not look like Bookdown's gitbook)
Resolved (see bottom)
I'm new to R, RStudio, and Bookdown so any help is appreciated!
Versions:
I am trying to implement a workshop that uses R, using Bookdown's Gitbook project template. I've been trying to implement R chunks and tables, and learn more about how the table of contents is produced. (It may note be relevant, at some point the bookdown::pdf_book could not build, but bookdown::gitbook and bookdown::epub_book could. Currently, the generated epub file is a binary file I can't open.)
Here is the R code that caused problems initially:
{r, out.width= "65%", out.extra='style="padding-right: 10%;"'}
knitr::include_graphics("./_main_files/figure-html/nice-fig-1.png")

I also created and deleted a very simple Markdown file. Soon after, my book stopped building into a regular book, and now looks like a weird HTML version.


I am trying to figure out what went wrong and how to change it so that it builds into a regular Gitbook.
I've commented out all R chunks. All R markdown files either are unedited files that came with the template, or reasonably simple R markdown files. I have checked _output.yml and _bookdown.yml, and they essentially match the template version (though I added output_dir: "docs" to _bookdown.yml).
It seems to me somewhere in the build/config files, something changed so that the book no longer builds to look like a normal gitbook. When running bookdown::render_book() and then warnings(), I get these warnings:
Warning messages:
1: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/jquery-3.6.0/jquery-3.6.0.min.js', reason 'Permission denied'
2: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/css/style.css', reason 'Permission denied'
3: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/css/plugin-table.css', reason 'Permission denied'
4: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/css/plugin-bookdown.css', reason 'Permission denied'
5: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/css/plugin-highlight.css', reason 'Permission denied'
6: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/css/plugin-search.css', reason 'Permission denied'
7: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/css/plugin-fontsettings.css', reason 'Permission denied'
8: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/css/plugin-clipboard.css', reason 'Permission denied'
9: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/js/app.min.js', reason 'Permission denied'
10: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/js/plugin-search.js', reason 'Permission denied'
11: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/js/jquery.highlight.js', reason 'Permission denied'
12: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'docs/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/js/plugin-clipboard.js', reason 'Permission denied'

I am not sure what is wrong here since I have rwx permissions for these folders.
I tried using GitHub to see what config files have changed after I built a default bookdown gitbook, but I only saw the epub and pdf files being changed, and no config files that I could actually read.
I also tried creating another very basic Markdown file in a new bookdown gitbook template, and it renders fine, so it may not be related to the Markdown file (but if it isn't I have no clue what it is).
Please help if you can!!!
Solution:
Update the mods of the docs folder:
chmod -R u+w docs
in terminal.
(Note: ls -ld docs gave me the same output before and after this command).
I also updated RStudio.
